# How can I return a properly formatted title, for use in a URI in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

In yii2 framework, which is the similar function as `url::title()` in Kohana? An example would be

`$input_title = ' __Ecléçtic__ title\'s  entered by cràzed users- ?>  ';`

`echo url::title($input_title, '_');`

Generates:

`eclectic_titles_entered_by_crazed_users`

Comment: Please explain better what do you mean for title ?  the route? the url? or other?

Comment: Just check the example. Basically I mean text.

Answer (score 1):

[This project](https://github.com/cocur/slugify) will help you.

Code example:

```
$slugify->activateRuleset('esperanto');
echo $slugify->slugify('serĉi manĝi'); // sercxi-mangxi
```

Comment: Thanks I was hoping there would be something built in Yii2 but guess I will have to write my own functions.

Comment: You can simple add this package to yii2 through composer. You need code example?

Answer (score 0):

Since I have received no suggestion on what Yii2 method to use I wrote this one on my custom helpers. The Slugify package suggested is also good but one function was enough for me.

```
    public static function title($title, $separator = '-')
  {
          $separator = ($separator === '') ? '' : '-';

          // Remove all characters that are not the separator, a-z, 0-9, or whitespace and arabic lang
          $title = preg_replace ( "/&([\x{0600}-\x{06FF}a-zA-Z])(uml|acute|grave|circ|tilde|ring),/u", "", $title );
          $title = preg_replace ( "/[^\x{0600}-\x{06FF}a-zA-Z0-9_ .-]/u", "", $title );

          // Remove all characters that are not the separator, a-z, 0-9, or whitespace
          //        $title = preg_replace('/[^'.$separator.'a-z0-9\s]+/', '', strtolower($title));

          // Replace all separator characters and whitespace by a single separator
          $title = preg_replace('/['.$separator.'\s]+/', $separator, $title);

          // Trim separators from the beginning and end
          return trim($title, $separator);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you do have sluggable behavior built in to yii. [Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior.html).

In your model you have to update the behaviors:

```
use yii\behaviors\SluggableBehavior;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => 'title',
        ],
    ];
}
```

I always use the id as part of the slug, to ensure uniqueness.

```
'urlManager' => [
        'rules' => [
            '<id:\d+>/<slug:[A-Za-z0-9 -_.]+>' => '<controller>/view',
        ]
 ]
```